# Wiregurad запущен, но не слушает на порту

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard, digitalocean

На vps-сервере Ubuntu запущен wiregurad. Должен слушать на порту 51830. Systemctl показывает, что сервис запущен (active). Но в netstat -tulpn вижу что порт 51830 не прослушивается (нет статуса LISTEN):

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 51830
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51830           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::51830                :::*                                -
```

Собственно, проблема: не могу подключиться клиентом wireguard к серверу (пробовал с windows и ubuntu), также не могу достучаться до сервера по порту 51830 (пробовал через nc и через сайты првоерки открытости портов на сервере). На самой vps (digital ocean) порты точно не блокируются.

Не могу понять, почему wireguard корректно запущен, но не слушает порт?

Конфиг wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = mMjMG4Q...
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51830
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = Mivy00...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = 60+TD9X...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
```

Comment: У UDP и не бывает `LISTEN` в выводе netstat. Так что кто-то порт таки слушает. Что бы работал флаг `p` нужно запускать netstat от рута.

Comment: Получается wireguard нормально работает? Но почему-то тогда порт 51830 с другого хоста я не могу прозвонить

Comment: Проверяйте файрвол. Проверьте что подключение работает с этого же хоста.

Comment: В фаерволе у меня есть такая строчка:
`51830/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere`
Но неткат выдаёт:
`netcat -zvn 127.0.0.1 51830 netcat: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 51830 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`
На самом впс в панели админа digital ocean создал правило для udp 51830 разрешить входящие.
В iptables тоже ок `sudo iptables --list | grep 51830
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51830
`

Comment: Вы пытаетесь установить TCP соединение на порту, который слушает по UDP, это так не работает, особенно на WG, который обычно на такие простые "стучалки" вообще никак не реагирует, а поэтому вы без правильного запроса от клиента WG вообще не получите ответ.